# How can I remove all space in string?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing so:

```
var mystring = "I am beginner in JS"
    console.log(mystring.trim())
```

The code above is removing only space on the left and on the right.
I need to get "IambeginnerinJS".

Answer (score 2):

use a regex:

```
"I am a beginner".replace(/\s+/g,'');
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this
    `mystring.replace(/\s/g, '')`
It might work for you

Answer (score 1):

**You can either use RegEx:**

```
'I am a beginner in JS'.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

**Or split/join:**

```
'I am a beginner in JS'.split(' ').join('');
```